# How to import Dump of 12.2 to 12.1.0.2.0 (Higher to lower version)?

Tags: oracle

I took a backup of one database using expdp utility. Unfortunately, this database had been corrupted. I have another oracle server installed on another machine. I want to import available dump to this database. But this available database is in lower version 12.1.0.2.0.

ORA-39001: invalid argument value ORA-39000: bad dump file specification ORA-39142: incompatible version number 5.1 in dump file "D:\DB Administration\Backup Guides\Oracle Docs\dump\BACKUP_FULL_20200625.DMP"

I have tried expdp and sql developer to import in oracle 12.1.0.2.0. Found not a valid export.

OS: Windows server 2016

Utility : expdp

Comment: What have you tried? I'm asking this because I'd want to avoid offering solutions that you have already determined unsuitable.

Comment: I have tried expdp and sql developer to import in oracle 12.1.0.2.0. Found not a valid export.the exact message will be provided when trying again

Comment: ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39142: incompatible version number 5.1 in dump file "D:\DB Administration\Backup Guides\Oracle Docs\dump\BACKUP_FULL_20200625.DMP"

Comment: You should edit your question to add this valuable information, instead of leaving them in comments.